# Flash .fla file into Sony Vegas timeline?

Tags: adobe-flash, sony-vegas

What is the best way to get a flash cs5 file (.fla) into Sony Vegas timeline, in order to join it with others Vegas stuff?

I'm using win xp sp3 and Vegas Pro 10.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a `.fla` file is analogous as that of a `.doc` file. Let's put it like this:

> Your `fla` is like the recipe of a cake, and everytime you *compile* it into an `swf` movie, 
>   the program actually reads the recipe and bakes a new cake.

So rather than trying to insert your *recipe* (`fla`) you may want to compile the move (`swf`) or even an `flv` movie and try to insert that into your Vegas timeline. Though you may need [the right codecs](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=flv%20codec) or plugins to do so.

A quick google search for "*import swf in sony vegas*" threw me [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wdDwXLix9s).

And this is a [**good codec pack**](http://www.codecguide.com/download_kl.htm) that contains the `flv` codec.

**Update**:

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySkdvLjw6h8) shows how to import an actual `swf` movie to Vegas Pro 10 by following these steps:

1. Open the `Export configurations` dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>).
2. Select the `Flash` tab.
3. Change the `Player` option to `FlashPlayer 5` or `FlashPlayer 6`.
4. Disable the `Compress movie` option.
5. Click accept to close the dialog and export the `swf` movie again and it should work.

Comment: arielnmz, It doesn't work. I installed K-lite 10.5.5. Basic, run Vegas and tried to drag a .swf file on Vegas timeline, but the cursor changes to "not allowed" !

Comment: Did you try the link I provided to "*import swf in sony vegas*"? It's most likely that you can't (less than importing a `fla` though), that's why I suggested the `flv` solution too.

Comment: Yes I tried that converter, and please stop recommend me a solution which you did not ever try ! Thanks.

Comment: @bonaca: so you tried by throwing the .fla file at the converter or what exactly?

Comment: @bonaca Did you even try to convert it to flv? Also, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySkdvLjw6h8) (it was on the related videos column) shows how to import an `swf` on Vegas Pro 10 by exporting the `fla` as a FlashPlayer 6 `swf` movie and by disabling movie compression. Please do some research before asking.